# How to grey out whole page when loader is getting called?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `<div id="loader"></div>` in html that only show's up when ajax is running in Jquery. Now This loader is only a simple spinning loading icon that i got from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp, but I want to make the background grey as well, so it's easier to see the loading icon. But I couldn't figure out on how to do this

Here is my css:

```css
#loader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

and this is how I show my loader in jquery:

```js
// Does the following if Ajax starts
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#loader").show();
});

// Does the following if Ajax stops
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#loader").hide();
    $('#cancelBtn').removeAttr('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to update your html, you could get a nice effect by using a drop shadow:

```css
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  background: #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #aaa;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Always use class selector it is a good practice and use max z-index value for any loading,modal etc to overlap other elements

Just warp the loader in div and apply the below css rules.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.loader {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgray;
  z-index: 999;/* max value*/
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.loader > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='loader'>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the colour to the background you just have to add one more property to the `#loader`:

```
background-color: #f3f3f3;
```

If you want to add a background to the full width of the page, you can add div:

```
<div class='content'>
 The content is not visible when animation is active!

  <div class="container">
    <div id="loader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with CSS properties:

```
.container {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  z-index: 9999;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You can also modify your jQuery code to toggle your animation:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $(".container").css("display", "flex");
});

// Does the following if Ajax stops
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $(".container").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Hi! You can make your code executable directly in StackOverflow. Use the `<>` button. You can even choose to add jQuery and more on the left in that editor.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your loader in a div, like so:

```css
.loader-container {
   display: flex;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 10;
   background-color: grey;
}

.loader {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 11;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   margin: auto;
   border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
   -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
   animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-container">
   <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```